# What steps to follow when to publish an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-developer-program

As being first app, When is right time to buy APPLE's Student Program for Developer's Account so as to put app in iphone for debugging and testing purposes?
or is there any way to put apps in iphone without having dev acc. ? AND can we use same dev accounts on two MACs because app being developed on two different macs?

Answer (score 0):

The right time to buy a developer's account is when you want to actually test the application on a iOS device rather than just the simulator since the simulator is not as reliant. And there is no way to put an iOS app on an apple device without having a developer's account. And yes, you can use the same developer's account on multiple macs.